# OpencCV HoughLines does not find vertical lines

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform, houghlines

I need to process tables and I decided to use openCV in python. However, at the first stage, I ran into a problem that the program does not find the lines that I am looking for. See the sample code below.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('./sssr/narodnoe_hozyaystvo_sssr_za_1913-1955_gg_page-0111.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, threshold_image = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, 0)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150, apertureSize=3)
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, 300)

for line in lines:
    for r, theta in line:
        a = np.cos(theta)
        b = np.sin(theta)
        x0 = a * r
        y0 = b * r
        x1 = int(x0 + 1000 * (-b))
        y1 = int(y0 + 1000 * (a))
        x2 = int(x0 - 1000 * (-b))
        y2 = int(y0 - 1000 * (a))
        cv2.line(threshold_image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imwrite('linesDetected.jpg', threshold_image)
```

The the result is:

[result of HoughLines transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIWkg.jpg)

The program finds many lines that I don’t need. It can’t determine the vertical borders of the table header.

Comment: Did you read the houghlines/houghlinesP documentation? Read what the `thresh` parameter does. You use value `300` - those are long lines.

Comment: Can I upvote this post for "Best Stackoverflow Joke of 2020"?

Comment: You're going to have to work quite hard to detect those vertical lines (which look like they are exclamation marks) without noise. Garbage in, garbage out.